# Result of move folder with NTFS permissions - Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows, permissions, file-server

Let's say we have this situation:

On a Windows 2003 file server, the following structure is present:

\fileserver\folder1\subfolder1
Which has NTFS access permissions for UserA

\fileserver\folder2\ 
Which has NTFS access permissions for UserB

If I just simply move \fileserver\folder1\subfolder1 to  \fileserver\folder2\subfolder1 what happens to the permissions ?

Will UserA still have their permissions to the 'subfolder1' location or will the permissions change to UserC and UserD ?

How can I make this move, but keep initial permissions ?

Comment: What keeps you from simply trying it yourself with dummy folders?

Comment: Because creating a new folder on that server, even for testing, takes around 3 days of requests, approvals and procedures.

Comment: Get rid of Windows 2003 - NOW!

Comment: I proposed them to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you aren't the server admin if you need 3 days of requests and approvals to create a folder.

However, assuming that \fileserver\folder1 and \fileserver\folder2 are two separate shares, this KB article should answer your question depending on if you can figure out if those shares are on the same physical volume on the server or not.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310316/how-permissions-are-handled-when-you-copy-and-move-files-and-folders